# TSQL inner select value in Outer Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query that I slimmed down to a very basic example of what I am trying to do.

My issue is that I am creating a dynamic `WHERE` clause on my tool but can't even get the simple select below to work.

I have a table called `BS_TrainingEvent_Segments` that contains training events. An event can have multiple segments. My outer Where clause needs to be able to query both the Inner and Outer select but at the point it's at, it just says `B cannot be bound`.

```
SELECT A.[teSegmentID],
       A.[trainingEventID],
       A.[segmentDate],
       A.[nonProdHrs],
      (
             SELECT B.[recordID],
                    B.[segmentID],
                    B.[localeID],
                    B.[teammateCount],
                    B.[leaderCount]
                 FROM dbo.BS_TrainingEvent_SegmentDetails AS B
                 WHERE A.teSegmentID = segmentID
                 FOR    XML PATH ('detail'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('details')
      ) AS B
FROM [red].[dbo].[BS_TrainingEvent_Segments] AS A
WHERE A.[teCategory] = 'Food' AND B.[localeID] = '462'
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root')
```

Comment: Looks like it should be ok. Can you create a sqlfiddle?

Comment: Looks like you cannot have B.[LocaleID] in WHERE clause because there is no such column LocaleID exists. You are referencing it as Derived column which is not in this case. B is just one column and not table.

Comment: So that is my question.. How can I query data from the inner select in the outer where clause?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.[teSegmentID],
    A.[trainingEventID],
    A.[segmentDate],
    A.[nonProdHrs],
    (
        SELECT B.[recordID],
            B.[segmentID],
            B.[localeID],
            B.[teammateCount],
            B.[leaderCount]
        FROM dbo.BS_TrainingEvent_SegmentDetails AS B
        WHERE A.teSegmentID = B.segmentID AND B.[localeID] = '462'
        FOR XML PATH ('detail'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('details')
    )
FROM [red].[dbo].[BS_TrainingEvent_Segments] AS A
WHERE A.[teCategory] = 'Food'
FOR XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```